# Vue.js this.$refs empty due to v-if

Tags: vue.js

I have a simple Vue component that displays an address, but converts into a form to edit the address if the user clicks a button.  The address field is an autocomplete using Google Maps API.  Because the field is hidden (actually nonexistent) half the time, I have to re-instantiate the autocomplete each time the field is shown.

```js
<template>
  <div>

    <div v-if="editing">
      <div><input ref="autocomplete" v-model="address"></div>
      <button @click="save">Save</button>
    </div>

    <div v-else>
      <p>{{ address }}</p>
      <button @click="edit">Edit</button>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    editing: false,
    address: ""
  },
  methods: {
    edit() {
      this.editing = true;
      this.initAutocomplete();
    },
    save() {
      this.editing = false;
    }
    initAutocomplete() {
      this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.$refs.autocomplete, {});
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.initAutocomplete();
  }
}
```

I was getting errors that the autocomplete reference was not a valid `HTMLInputElement`, and when I did `console.log(this.$refs)` it only produced `{}` even though the input field was clearly present on screen.  I then realized it was trying to reference a nonexistent field, so I then tried to confine the autocomplete init to only when the input field should be visible via `v-if`.  Even with this, `initAutocomplete()` is still giving errors trying to reference a nonexistent field.

How can I ensure that the reference exists first?

Comment: Change `v-if` directive to `v-show`. `v-if` doesn't render element at all on false condition that's why $refs doesn't contain your element. `v-show` always renders element and just hides with `display:none` on false condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe a solution would be to use [$nextTick](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) which will wait for your DOM to rerender.

So your code would look like :

```
edit() {
  this.editing = true;
  this.$nextTick(() => { this.initAutocomplete(); });
},
```

Moreover if you try to use your `this.initAutocomplete();` during `mounting` it cannot work since the `$refs.autocomplete` is not existing yet but I'm not sure you need it since your v-model is already empty.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because your "refs" is plural

```
<input refs="autocomplete" v-model="address">
```

It should be:

```
<input ref="autocomplete" v-model="address">
```

Comment: good catch.  actually a typo from coding in the browser, but thank you!